# Missing salt: Why is the salt not complete after using hashpw (bcrypt)?

Tags: r, hash, cryptography, bcrypt, salt

While making a save password we can use a salt for hashing. This is done with the `bcrypt`  package but the hashed password does not contain the full salt text. See here:

```
library("bcrypt")
my_password <- "password1"
my_salt <- "$2a$10$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv"
hashpw(my_password, my_salt)
[1] "$2a$10$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuu2njjerFUdKeNqVoGia/slSqhJQ.vuAy"
```

So the salt I used was `"$2a$10$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv"` but the text in the hashed password only contains the salt up to the letter `u`. But [here](https://auth0.com/blog/hashing-in-action-understanding-bcrypt/) it is said that: "Looking at a previous hash/salt result, notice how the hash is the salt with the hash appended to it".

Comment: [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt#Description) uses a 16 byte salt (22 characters in Radix-64). A salt that is too long will be truncated accordingly.

Comment: @Topaco I am using the shortest possible salt I think. In the question my salt contains the first 22 letters of the alphabet, see here: `hashpw(my_password, paste0("$2a$10$", paste0(letters[1:22], collapse= ""), collapse= ""))`. But if we use 21 letters instead `hashpw(my_password, paste0("$2a$10$", paste0(letters[1:21], collapse= ""), collapse= ""))` we get the error `Invalid salt`.

Comment: The bcrypt salt is Radix-64 encoded 22 characters long. A 21 character salt is too short, hence the error message. Try to generate a salt with `gensalt()`. Maybe I misunderstand you.

Comment: @Topaco In your first comment you say that a salt with more than `22` characters will be truncated. What I say above is that my salt has excactly 22 characters. See what I get using `gensalt(log_rounds= 10)`: "$2a$10$0bboS2soT8klOBwvVMw1fe". Here, as in my question, the `$2y$10` is not part of the salt but is information about the algorithm (see picture [here](https://www.php.net/manual/de/faq.passwords.php) ). If you remove those information from the salt in my question you see that I am using the first 22 letters of the alphabet as the salt.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the salt must end with `"."`, `"O"`, `"e"` or `"u"` in `bcrypt`. You can see here that this is the case:

```
# Generate a bunch of salts
library("bcrypt")
lots_salt <- NULL
for(i in 1:99999) {
  lots_salt[i] <- gensalt(10)  
}
# See unique last character
salt_end <- unique(substring(lots_salt, nchar(lots_salt[1]), nchar(lots_salt[1])))
salt_end
[1] "." "O" "e" "u"
```

Now we use the salt from the question but with one of the valid last characters `"."`, `"O"`, `"e"` or `"u"` and we indeed get back the salt we used in the resulting hash:

```
sapply(salt_end, function(salt_end_i){
  substring(hashpw(my_password, paste0(my_salt, salt_end_i)), 8, 8+21)
})
```

On the other hand, we get salts in the reulting hash that differ from the input salt if we use other last characters than `"."`, `"O"`, `"e"` or `"u"`. See here for example:

```
sapply(letters, function(salt_end_i){
  substring(hashpw(my_password, paste0(my_salt, salt_end_i)), 8, 8+21)
})
```

Thus, the resulting hash salt is not complete for the salt used in the question because it does not use `"."`, `"O"`, `"e"` or `"u"` as the last characters. The questions why only `"."`, `"O"`, `"e"` or `"u"` are valid as last characters remains though.

Comment: With a 16 bytes salt, 2 padding bytes are appended. Of the 128 bits of the salt, 126 bits can be grouped into 21 blocks of 6 bits each. The last two bits can only form the blocks 000000, 010000, 100000 and 110000, which are mapped to the chars `.`, `O`, `e` and `u` in the bcrypt Base64 variant. All following blocks consist of zero bits due to padding and are ignored by the bcrypt Base64 variant. This is the reason why all salts generated with `gensalt()` contain one of these 4 chars at the end. The salt with the ending sequence `uv` is not a regular bcrypt Base64 encoding and thus not valid.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a salt is *not* 22 characters of the base-64 alphabet, a salt is 16 bytes that are base64 encoded. You're observation shows the difference.